# Treadmills and DialogFlow - Assigning Multiple Entitites to One Word?

Tags: dialogflow-es

**The Project:** Using DialogFlow + Google Assistant to control a treadmill.

**The Problem:** Some vague commands are clear to English-speakers, but don't fit into the Entity groups I've made. (Sometimes one word fits into two entities.)

Below are few basic commands that fit neatly into my entities in addition to harder training phrases that I can't figure out how to fit into my existing current setup.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
Intents:
    Increase Speed
    Decrease Speed
    Increase Incline
    Decrease Incline

Entities:
    Direction
        - up, increase
        - down, decrease 
    Mechanism
        - speed
        - incline, decline

Training Phrases:
    Easy & Work Well:
        Increase the speed
        Decrease the incline
        Speed up
        Incline down
        Put the incline down
        Turn up the speed
        Bump the incline down
    Harder (One word = 2 entities?)
        Go slower ("Slower" is both direction (down) and mechanism (speed))
        Go faster (Same as case as above)
        Incline (Alone, assumption is both direction (up) and mechanism)
        Decline (Always means a direction (down) and mechanism)
```

As you can see, the main issue is that sometimes a single word can match two entities at once. **What's the best way to solve the harder training phrases?**

The flow of the application will be very simple. The user would talk to the app and expect one intent to be fired. This wouldn't be a long conversation and right now I'd like to get this to just a MVP level of working before doing any more complex stuff.

Comment: i dont think while running on a treadmill, anyone will mean incline/decline in terms of speed. and slower/faster will always be speed.

Comment: @sid8491 Correct, incline/decline are pretty straightforward. The only caveat is for "incline". Users can say "incline down" since "incline" is generally used by people as the default state of things, even though it really means "Cline Up"

Comment: How is slower / faster being used for inclination?

Comment: @NilsSens it isn't / shouldn't be, did I mess up somewhere?

Comment: ""Slower" is both direction (down) and mechanism (speed)" for me, slower only refers to speed.